# GPay sheet on WEB does not show loading sometimes when calculating shipping fee

Tags: google-pay

I'm implementing a feature to allow users purchase items and pay by Google Pay with shipping address is entered on GPay sheet then shipping fee will be calculated and updated to total amount. But sometimes when I open payment sheet with an existing address the loading icon is not showed while calculating shipping fee.

[image: Getting shipping fee but loading is not showing]

[image: Complete getting shipping fee and total amount is updated correctly]

I implemented onPaymentDataChanged and return promise correctly but I don't know why sometimes GPay sheet showing loading to prevent user click on PAY button while calculating shipping fee but sometime does not. Anyone have experience on this, please help!

Answer (score 1):

Have you got some sample code to show what you've done so far?

I've put together the following [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8dfmb7h1/):

```js
button.onPaymentDataChanged = paymentData => {
  // The below promise is used to simulate calling an API to calculate shipping
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const shippingOption = shippingOptions.find(o => o.id === paymentData.shippingOptionData.id);
      const { displayItems } = paymentRequest.transactionInfo;
      let response = {};
      if (displayItems) {
        const shippingItem = displayItems.find(i => i.label === 'Shipping');
        if (shippingItem && shippingOption) {
          shippingItem.price = shippingOption.price;
          shippingItem.status = 'FINAL';

          response = {
            newTransactionInfo: {
              ...paymentRequest.transactionInfo,
              displayItems: displayItems,
              totalPrice: displayItems.reduce((sum, i) => sum + parseFloat(i.price), 0).toFixed(2),
            }
          };
        }
      }
      resolve(response);
    }, 3000);
  });
}
```

The most important thing is that you return something in the `onPaymentDataChanged` method. It can be [`PaymentDataRequestUpdate`](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/reference/request-objects#PaymentDataRequestUpdate) object, or a promise that resolves the same object.

FYI, the JSFiddle uses the [Google Pay custom element](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-pay/button-element). A [React version](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-pay/button-react) is also available if using React.

---

Update in response to [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63554748/google-pays-payment-sheet-on-web-does-not-show-loading-sometime-when-calculatin/63679200?noredirect=1#comment112639278_63679200):

I think I was able to reproduce. However, for me, it only appeared to show the *correct* price the first time I clicked the button (*sometimes*). Which leads me to think that the initial value may be cached. Subsequent clicks on the button always displayed the original price and then a *silent* update. This sounds like a bug to me.

As a workaround, you could try updating `paymentRequest` when handling `onPaymentDataChanged`. See updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k6smgnqL/):

```
button.onPaymentDataChanged = paymentData => {
          // ...
          response = {
            newTransactionInfo: {
              ...paymentRequest.transactionInfo,
              displayItems: displayItems,
              totalPrice: displayItems.reduce((sum, i) => sum + parseFloat(i.price), 0).toFixed(2),
            }
          };
          paymentRequest.transactionInfo = response.newTransactionInfo;
          // ...
}
```

Comment: If you already set up shipping address you can try this JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/q7wdp2bh/ and reproduce the issue by clicking on GPay button then close and repeat and repeat, you can see sometimes the loading icon is appear until the promise is resolved but sometime it shows the initial total price first then silently update the amount after the promise is resolve with new transaction info.

Comment: Updated answer based on your comment.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer @soc, I'm going to try your workaround solution.